# Google Calendar Api - convert DataTime to Calendar object

Tags: java, android, datetime, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to convert this DataTime object to Calendar object.

*DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();*

DateTime format: *2015-11-11T19:25:55.000Z*
I need format: *"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"*

How can I cut TimeZone and convert it to Calendar object?

**Original Google Calendar Api:**

```
private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
    // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
    DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    List<String> eventStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
            .setMaxResults(10)
            .setTimeMin(now)
            .setOrderBy("startTime")
            .setSingleEvents(true)
            .execute();
    List<Event> items = events.getItems();
    for (Event event : items) {
        DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
        if (start == null) {
            // All-day events don't have start times, so just use
            // the start date.
            start = event.getStart().getDate();
        }
        eventStrings.add(String.format("%s (%s)", event.getSummary(),start));
    }
    return eventStrings;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse your 2015-11-11T19:25:55.000Z into an actual Date object. Once you've got that Date object, it's as easy as:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(your_date_object);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying do somthing with it, but its not work.

```
            DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
            String newDate = dateFormat.format(start);
```

Maybe someone know why i can't parse this data

```
            DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
            String NewDate = String.format("(%s)", start);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ", Locale.getDefault());
            cal.setTime(sdf.parse(NewDate));
```

All the time i have unparseable date exception.

I tried formats:

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
>
> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ
>
> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
SimpleDateFormat dtExibicao = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date dtInicio = new Date(event.getStart().getDateTime().getValue());
String stInicio = dtExibicao.format(dtInicio);
```

If you wanna a java.util.Calendar you can use a @k3v1n4ud3 sample code:

```
java.util.Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(dtInicio);
```